# What is a Single Word™?

Tags: pattern, english, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Single Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Single Words™ | Non Single Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| water | food |
| bear | grizzly |
| beeswax | honey |
| zebra | horse |
| deer | buck |
| rat | mouse |
| cat | feline |
| dad | father |
| mom | mother |
| you | me |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Single Words™, Non Single Words™
water, food
bear, grizzly
beeswax, honey
zebra, horse
deer, buck
rat, mouse
cat, feline
dad, father
mom, mother
you, me
```

Comment: Can you confirm that mouse is Non single???

Comment: @greenturtle3141 yes mouse is non single

Comment: Aw... I really thought that single words were words containing a letter with a different height from the others.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 i didn't realize i was so close to fit with another rule!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A Single Words™ looks like one which

> Is typed using just one hand with a standard keyboard touch typing method
>
>  Left hand letters are Q, W, E, R, T ,  A, S, D, F, G ,  Z, X, C, V, B
>
>  Right hand letters are Y, U, I, O, P , H, J, K, L , N, M
>
>  [image]
>
>  And the Non Single Words™ need both hands to touch type.

Comment: Nicely Done!  This is the answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at all sure that I understand the rationale, but,
a Non Single word is

> one that contains at least one of the letters
> `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` and/or `n`,
> and/or contains both letters `m` and `e`.

A Single word, obviously, is one that does not conform to the above rule.

> My best guess is that it has something to do
> with the first-person singular pronouns, "I" and "me" — something like
>
> > it's not single if I'm there with it
>
> ?
> The letters `f`, `g`, `h`, `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` and `n`
> are the letters between `e` and `o`, 
> which are the last vowel before `i` and the first vowel after `i`.

> Yes, I know there are no words in the table that contain `j`. 
> Or `p`, `q`, or `v`. 
> I assume that's just to avoid making it too easy.

Comment: My experience is that answers like this are (usually) frowned upon.